# Pine script for refreshing chrat on Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I was wondering if there is a possibility to make a script that refreshes the chart after 5 min.

Because if you refresh your script it solves the repainting issue.

Love to hear if somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do that and ideally you should avoid repainting.

[Events](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#events-triggering-the-execution-of-a-script) that trigger the execution of a script:

- A new symbol or resolution is loaded on a chart.
- A script is saved or added to the chart from the Pine Editor.
- A value is modified in the script’s Settings/Inputs dialog box.
- A value is modified in a strategy’s Settings/Properties dialog box.
- A browser refresh event is detected.

Refreshing the page is not a solution to the repainting. There are several methods to avoid it.

- [How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)
- [How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security](https://www.tradingview.com/script/s8kWs84i-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security/)